# Clearing an Expando class in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to replace a Groovy `Map` object that I am heavily using for various data with an `Expando` class object. However, since currently the `Map` object is re-used several times in my code, I also want to clear all data associated to it.

So by now I am simply calling `map.clear()` in order to remove all data from the `Map` object. Is there a similar approach for an `Expando` class in Groovy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clear an `Expando` instance by calling `.properties.clear()`. Try the following in the Groovy console

```
def ex = new Expando()

ex.foo = 'fooVal'
ex.bar = 'barVal'

assert 2 == ex.properties.size()

ex.properties.clear()
assert 0 == ex.properties.size()
```